# What is the best way to update my NSMutablearray count in tableview delegate after retrieving the count from an api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, tableview

Basically, I need my UITableView to retrieve the correct amount of array of results from an API. I retrieve the array of results from the api through didGetResults method ,however the array count still stays at zero for the tableview delegate even when the array count changes inside the didGetResults. How do I update the result count in my tableview delegate as soon as I get the array of results? I will post my code to give you a better idea on what I am trying to do.

ViewController.h

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <Appdelegate>{
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *resultArray;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

ViewController.m

```
   -(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return self.resultArray.count;
   }

  -(void)didGetResult:(NSMutableArray*)jsonArray{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  self.resultArray = jsonArray;
  NSLog(@"resultArrayCount %@",self.resultArray.count);
  }
```

The resultArray count changes in the didGetResults, but it doesn't update resultArray count in the numberOfRows tableview delegate.
Edit: Also, the didGetResult is a delegate and the jsonArray is the amount of results it retrieves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it the wrong way around. Update the data source first, and then reload the
table view:

```
self.resultArray = jsonArray;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

And if `didGetResult:` is called on a background thread, you have to dispatch
these calls to the main thread, because UI updates must only be done on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.resultArray = jsonArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOW!!! This was driving me up the wall. Good spot, will approve answer as soon as I am allow to (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reloadData` **after** updating the array:

```
- (void)didGetResult:(NSMutableArray *)jsonArray {
    self.resultArray = jsonArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `[self.tableView reloadData];` after you set resultsArray `self.resultArray = jsonArray`.

```
   -(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return self.resultArray.count;
   }

  -(void)didGetResult:(NSMutableArray*)jsonArray{
  self.resultArray = jsonArray;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  NSLog(@"resultArrayCount %@",self.resultArray.count);
  }
```

You will need to implement `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` too.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `reloadData`, it refreshes the table, so that's when it calls the delegate methods. In your implementation:

```
-(void)didGetResult:(NSMutableArray*)jsonArray{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.resultArray = jsonArray;
    NSLog(@"resultArrayCount %@",self.resultArray.count);
}
```

You're reloading the data before you update your array, which means it will give you the old count. You need to switch the two lines around so it's like this:

```
-(void)didGetResult:(NSMutableArray*)jsonArray{
    self.resultArray = jsonArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"resultArrayCount %@",self.resultArray.count);
}
```

That way when it calls the delegate methods, it's using your new data.